# How can I access columns from another joined table in twig symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have two entities - News, Category. Using DQL, I created query like this:

```
SELECT  n,c
FROM    MyDemoBundle:News n
INNER JOIN MyDemoBundle:Category c
WHERE   n.category_id = c.id
    AND c.id = :cid
    AND c.route = :route
    AND c.enabled = 1 
    AND n.status = 1
ORDER BY n.id DESC
```

My site is multilanguage, so I have columns like name_ru, name_en in Categories, and title_ru, title_en, article_ru, article_en, etc. in News.

In Twig, I need to display list of articles. I can do that like this:

```
{% for entity in articles %}    
<h2>{{ attribute(entity, 'title' ~ (app.request.attributes.get('_locale')|capitalize)) }}</h2>
<p>{{ attribute(entity, 'article' ~ (app.request.attributes.get('_locale')|capitalize))|raw }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But, for my language switcher in twig I need to fetch name_ru and name_en (Categories) from result. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by myself. Solution is:
    articles.0.category.nameEn

Answer (score 0):

Don"t forget to check if the value/object is correctly set.
Otherwise, you may encountered issue in that case.

Symfony/Twig is quite strict about it.